# symfony2 assetic not loaded (name issue)

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, assetic, assets

I use sf 2.3

And have next code

```
{% javascripts
   '@WebmilJointAssetsBundle/Resources/public/frontend/javascripts/app/controllers/*' filter='yui_js' 
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

in this folder I have files:

```
fos_user_profile_show.js
fos_user_registration_register.js
fos_user_security_login.js
homepage.js
```

All works ok.

Than I add `webmil_frontend_dress_add_dress.js`.  And this file does not load. I discover if file start from a - h letter it load. But if it start from  i - z  letter it doesn't work. So I add like `a_webmil_frontend_dress_add_dress.js` If anybody knows something about this?

Comment: This is indeed weird. What version of `assetic` do you use? Does this happen in `dev` or in `prod`? Did you `cache:clear` the app?

Comment: @jperovic thank you! It happen in `dev`. `cache:clear` fix my problem. Hm I think that in dev I don't need cache:clear... And why for a - h letter I don't need clear cache..